# From Jquery how to determine split delimiter?

Tags: javascript

Let's  if I have many split delimiters that I am going to use. How can I write a script in Jquery to determine the which delimiter to use for such case?

eg:  ee 11
     ee|11
     ee|11
     ee-11

If we take the above example, It should be spitted by checking the useage of delimiters - from the above list since '|' is twice, split should be done with '|' delimiter.

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Huh? Are you saying you don't know what all of the possible delimiters are? Do you at least know what characters the non-delimeters are? Or is the issue that there are _n_ specific possible delimiters and you need to determine which of those was used in any given string? Or...? If you imagine that there is a function to do what you want, what would be its input and output?

Comment: @Macon This is not a jQuery question.

Comment: @nnnnn  I do have a list of planned delimiters,I want from the parsing string It has determine and split and the best way to do it.

Comment: @Tomalak, thanks for ur concerns, I'm looking how to do it from jquery framework.

Comment: @Macon You wouldn't need to use any jQuery functions to do this (as my answer states).

Comment: @Macon Quizz question: What's the difference between jQuery and JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just split on either...

```
var chunks = str.split(/[ |-]/);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4DRd/).

Comment: Thanks Alex but I am looking for something like the question now, I'm sorry I had to revise the question I think I had mentioned few facts incorrectly.

Comment: example is like  name value  ee 11