# Extrapolate days from string with two delimeters

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, date, data-conversion

I have a string like this:

Mon - Thu, Sun

I would like to use javascript / jquery to convert this into the following:

Mon,Tues,Wed,Thu,Sun

Anyone have any ideas how this could be done?

Sorry @jonmrich I haven't posted here before. I was unaware i had to share what I had already looked into.

I looked at a couple of other stack Overflow questions/solutions
in particular

[regex split string with two separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39810097/regex-split-string-with-two-separators)

[From Jquery how to determine split delimiter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156871/from-jquery-how-to-determine-split-delimiter)

but couldn't figure out where to start.

I'll do better next time I ask ... thanks for the headsup.

Comment: You'll need to post some code to show what you've tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

- Create an array that will contain the abbreviated names of days. This is referred to in the below example as `dayNames`
- The string we want to extrapolate from is called `days` and consists of ranges of days, separated by a comma.
- A new array, `dayCodes` has been created to store the indices of the days in question. This code iterates through the ranges (in this case, Mon-Thur and Sun) and creates parameters for the specific range. If a range only has one day, its start value will be equal to its end value. The array will be populated with the indices that contain those items in the `dayNames` array.
- A new array named `matchedDays` was just created to map the indices with the day names. Iterate over the day codes (0-6) and push to the new array a slice of the `dayNames` array that matches our codes. The `slice` function comes in very handy here.
- Since this is a multidimensional array, we would like to flatten it. You can do it with `arr.reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b))`

**Fiddle**

```js
var dayNames = ["Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];
var days = "Mon - Thu, Sun"
var dayCodes = [];
var ranges = days.replace(/\s/g, "").split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    var parameters = ranges[i].split('-');
    var start = parameters[0];
    var end = parameters.length == 2 ? parameters[1] : start;
    dayCodes.push([dayNames.indexOf(start),  dayNames.indexOf(end)]);
}

var matchedDays = [];
for (var i = 0; i < dayCodes.length; i++) {
    if (dayCodes[i].length == 2) {
        matchedDays.push(dayNames.slice(dayCodes[i][0], dayCodes[i][1] + 1));
    }
  else {
      matchedDays.push(dayNames[dayCodes[i][0]]); 
  }
}

matchedDays = matchedDays.reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b));
console.log(matchedDays.join(', '));
```